# Set FillColor for Character

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a little issue with FillColor attribute. From scripting reference it seems that it is possible to set it with RGB color.

```
RGBColor RGB = new RGBColor();
.CharacterAtributes.FillColor = RGB;
```

But I keep getting error if I try to invert it

```
RGB = .CharacterAtributes.FillColor;
```

Even if add reference to RGB color

```
RGB = .CharacterAtributes.FillColor.RGBColor;
```

From what I know, `FillColor` should be `color` object which contains object of `RGBColor`. But if I check on debug it contains only CMYK values as double. Is it known glitch, or I am missing something to get fill color as RGB?

Thank you,

Michał

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of how color objects work is that FillColor will contain a color object that will have ONE of the following sub classes:

```
CMYKColor
GradientColor
GrayColor
LabColor
NoColor
PatternColor
RGBColor
SpotColor
```

It sounds like your fill color is set to a CMYKColor, if you need an RGBColor you will have to do a conversion from CMYK and create it with the converted values. There are no built in color conversion libraries in the scripting API that I am aware of, but there are several libraries available. Here is one I found quick [Javascript color conversion RGB, CMYK and HSV](https://gist.github.com/felipesabino/5066336)

Good luck.

Comment: From what I see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672714/changing-colors-in-illustrator-with-javascript they can get Reg/Green/Blue property of FillColor. I wonder why I can assign GRBColor to FillColor, but no FillColor to RGBColor.

Comment: If FillColor currently holds a CMYKColor object it can not be converted to an RGBColor object by way of assignment.  FillColor can have any type of color object assigned to it, but RGBColor objects can only have RBG values assigned to them. That's how I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I see whre was error in my understanding of `FillColor`. It will **be** any of those classes, not **have**:

```
CMYKColor
GradientColor
GrayColor
LabColor
NoColor
PatternColor
RGBColor
SpotColor
```

In that case assigment should look like this:

```
RGB.Red = .CharacterAtributes.FillColor.Red;
RGB.Green = .CharacterAtributes.FillColor.Green;
RGB.Blue = .CharacterAtributes.FillColor.Blue;
```

Michael

Comment: FillColor is an instance of Color:
An abstract parent class for all color classes used in Illustrator. Subclasses are:
CMYKColor
GradientColor
GrayColor
LabColor
NoColor
PatternColor
RGBColor
SpotColor